# Combining images that are "cut off" in ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to combine 2 images, which are identical in width, but vary in height. They are identical on the bottom/top side, but it's unknown how much.

1) Identify identical parts
2) Combine the images so the identical parts match

Example:
Part 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBrrt.png
Part 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc1Wd.png

Comment: Here's the original image: http://i.imgur.com/DFCUduU.png
(could not post more than 2 links)

Comment: You might like to have a look at - and maybe upvote :-) - my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219402/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-rows-of-two-images/27342865#27342865

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, I'll take a look and see if I can convert it to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Determine the image dimensions

Use `identify` to get width and height of each image:

```
identify                          \
   http://i.imgur.com/rZtAk2c.png \
   http://i.imgur.com/CQaQbr8.png

CQaQbr8.png PNG 701x974 720x994+10+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 33.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rZtAk2c.png PNG 701x723 720x773+10+46 8-bit sRGB 256c 25.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

### 2. Interpret the results

The results from the above command are these:

1. Both images *show* `701` pixels wide rows.
2. One image shows `974` different rows.
3. The other image shows `723` different rows.
4. But both images use a different *'canvas'* size.
5. The first image uses a `720x994` pixels canvas (offset of shown part is `+10+0`).
6. The second image uses a `720x773` pixels canvas (offset of shown part is `+10+46`).

### 3. Normalize the canvas to be identical with the shown pixels

We use the `+repage` image operator to normalize the canvas for both images:

```
convert CQaQbr8.png +repage img1.png
convert rZtAk2c.png +repage img2.png
```

[image]   [image]

### 4. Check both new images' dimensions again

```
identify img1.png img2.png

 img1.png PNG 701x974 701x974+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 33.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
 img2.png PNG 701x723 701x723+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 25.5KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

### 5. Learn, how to extract a single row from an image.

As an example, we extract row number 3 from `img1.png` (numbering starts with `0`):

```
convert img1.png[701x1+0+3] +repage img1---row3.png

identify img---row3.png
  img1---row3.png PNG 701x1 701x1+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 335B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

### 6. Learn, how to extract that same row in ImageMagick's 'txt' format:

```
convert img1.png[701x1+0+3] +repage img---row3.txt
```

If you are not familiar with the 'txt' format, here is an extract:

```
cat img---row3.txt
 # ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 701,1,255,gray
 0,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 1,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 2,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 3,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 4,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 5,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 6,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 7,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 8,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 9,0:   (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 [...skipping many lines...]
 695,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 696,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 697,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 698,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 699,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
 700,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
```

1. The 'txt' output file describes every pixel via a text line.
2. In each line the first column indicates the respective pixel's coordinates.
3. The second, third and fourth columns indicate the pixel's color in different ways (but they contain the same information each).

### 7. Convert each row into its 'txt' format and create its MD5 sum

This command also creates 'txt' output. But this time the 'target' file is given as `txt:-`. This means that the output is streamed to `<stdout>`.

```
for i in {0..973}; do                       \
  convert img1.png[701x1+0+${i}] txt:-      \
     | md5sum > md5sum--img1--row${i}.md5 ; \
done
```

This command creates 974 different files containing the MD5 sum of the 'txt' representation for the respective rows.

We can also write all MD5 sums into a single file:

```
for i in {0..973}; do                         \
  convert img1.png[701x1+0+${i}] txt:-        \
     | md5sum >> md5sum--img1--all-rows.md5 ; \
done
```

Now do the same thing for `img2.png`:

```
for i in {0..722}; do                         \
  convert img2.png[701x1+0+${i}] txt:-        \
     | md5sum >> md5sum--img2--all-rows.md5 ; \
done
```

### 8. Use `sdiff` to determine which lines of the `.md5` files match

We can use sdiff to compare the two `.md5` files line by line and write the output to a log file. The `nl -v 0` part of the following command automatically inserts the line number, starting with `0` into the result:

```
sdiff md5sum--img{1,2}--all-rows.md5 | nl -v 0 > md5sums.log
```

### 9. Check the `md5sums.log` for identical lines

```
 cat md5sums.log

     0                                       > 38c6cd70c39ffc853d1195a0da6474f8  -
     1                                       > 85100351b390ace5a7caca11776666d5  -
     2                                       > 66e2940dbb390e635eeba9a2944960dc  -
     3                                       > 8e93c1ed5c89aead8333f569cb768e4a  -
     4                                       > 8e93c1ed5c89aead8333f569cb768e4a  -
        [... skip many lines ...]
   172                                       > f9fece874b60fa1af24516c4bcee7302  -
   173                                       > edbe62592a3de60d18971dece07e3beb  -
   174                                       > 18a28776cc64ead860a99213644b0574  -
   175  0d0753c587dc3c46078ac265895a3f6c  -  | 0d0753c587dc3c46078ac265895a3f6c  -
   176  5ecc2b5a61af4120151fed4cd2c3d305  -  | 5ecc2b5a61af4120151fed4cd2c3d305  -
   177  3f2857594fe410dc7fe42b4bef724a87  -  | 3f2857594fe410dc7fe42b4bef724a87  -
   178  2fade815d804b6af96550860602ec1ba  -  | 2fade815d804b6af96550860602ec1ba  -
        [... skip many lines ...]
   719  127e6d52095db20f0bcb1fe6ff843da0  -  | 127e6d52095db20f0bcb1fe6ff843da0  -
   720  aef15dde4909e9c467f11a64198ba6d2  -  | aef15dde4909e9c467f11a64198ba6d2  -
   721  6320863dd7d747356f4b23fb7ba28a73  -  | 6320863dd7d747356f4b23fb7ba28a73  -
   722  2e32ceb7cc89d7bb038805e484dc7bc9  -  | 2e32ceb7cc89d7bb038805e484dc7bc9  -
   723  f9fece874b60fa1af24516c4bcee7302  -  <
   724  f9fece874b60fa1af24516c4bcee7302  -  <
   725  f9fece874b60fa1af24516c4bcee7302  -  <
   726  f9fece874b60fa1af24516c4bcee7302  -  <
        [... skip many lines ...]
  1146  3e18a7db0aed8b6ac6a3467c6887b733  -  <
  1147  62866c8ef78cdcd88128b699794d93e6  -  <
  1148  7dbed48a0e083d03a6d731a6864d1172  -  <
```

From this output we can conclude that rows 175 -- 722 in the `sdiff`-produced file all do match.

This means that there is a match in the following rows of the original images:

1. row `0` of `img1.png` matches row `175` of `img2.png` (begin of match).
   `img1.png` has a total of 974 rows of pixels.
2. row `547` of `img1.png` matches row `722` of `img2.png` (end of match).
   `img2.png` has a total of 723 rows of pixels.

(Remember, we used `0`-based row numbering...)

### 10. Put it all together now

From above investigations we can conclude, that we need only the first 174 rows from `img1.png` and append the full `img2.png` below that in order to get the correct result:

```
 convert img1.png[701x174+0+0] img2.png -append complete.png
```

[image]

---

<sub>***NOTES:***</sub>

<sub>There are many possible solutions (and methods to arrive there) to the problem posed by the OP. For example:</sub>

1. <sub>Instead of converting the rows to 'txt' format we could have used any other ImageMagick-supported format also (PNG, PPM, ...) and created the MD5 sums for comparison.</sub>
2. <sub>Instead of using `-append` to concatenate the two image parts, we could also have used `-composite` to superimpose them (with an appropriate offset, of course).</sub>
3. <sub>As @MarkSetchell says in his comment: instead of piping the 'pixel-rows' output to `md5sum` one could also use `-format '%#' info:-` to directly generate a hash value from the respective pixel-row. I had already forgotten about that option, because (years ago) I tried to use it for a similar purpose, and somehow it didn't work as I needed it. Which is why I became used to my 'piping to md5sum' approach...</sub>

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write such a detailed answer! I'll try to test this and accept the answer if it works. :)

Comment: Hi Kurt, You may want to add another note... I think you can get a checksum directly from IM like this `convert image.png[0x1+0+)] -format "%#" info:`

Comment: Thanks to your super detailed instructions, I managed to do everything in Python using Pillow! :) Here's the code too: http://pastebin.com/RRXfXV21 (it scans the directory for .png files, and expects them to be in the correct order, and doesn't do your step 3, but at least it works).

Comment: @Joona: My step 3 is a "Safety Net": Not required for most images, but still necessary for some. You only know if you need to apply it when you look at the input images first.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Yeah, I added it to the tool I used to capture the images so it was not necessary (or rather, it broke the images after a while). My suggestion is to only to do it if it's necessary (do a comparison).